# How to resolve the mismatch between OpenCl Library and OpenCl platform?

Tags: opencl, openvino

Openvino inference crashes. I think the source of issue is the note at the end of `clinfo` command:

```
your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 2.1, 
but some installed platforms support OpenCL 3.0. 
Programs using 3.0 features may crash or behave unexpectedly
```

How can I upgrade my OpenCL library to 3.0 to resolve the issue?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Kernel: 5.15.2-051502-generic

The content of `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/intel.icd` file is:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/intel-opencl/libigdrcl.so`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the latest Intel Compute Engine [21.45.21574](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/tag/21.45.21574) and see if it resolves the issue.